# Javascript to calculate input figures from form input

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a javascript that calculates the sum of 4 amounts, that is generated from the input fields.

The problem is, I want the Total Invoice Value to start reflecting the value after the user has inputted the Rate 1 and Amount 1 has shown. But it doesnt happen until all the 4 amounts have been generated. The Total Invoice Value reflect only after I input the amount in Rate 4.

The complete code I am working with right now is:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form name="register" id="myForm" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="register" method="POST">

Qty 1:<input type="number" step="any" name="Qty1" autocomplete="off" id="Qty1" required><br>
Rate 1:<input type="number" step="any" name="Rate1" autocomplete="off" id="Rate1" class="rate" required><br>
Amount 1:<input readonly type="number" step="any" name="Amt1" autocomplete="off" id="Amt1" required><br><br>

Qty 2:<input type="number" step="any" name="Qty2" autocomplete="off" id="Qty2" required><br>
Rate 2:<input type="number" step="any" name="Rate2" autocomplete="off" id="Rate2" class="rate" required><br>
Amount 2:<input readonly type="number" step="any" name="Amt2" autocomplete="off" id="Amt2" required><br><br>

Qty 3:<input type="number" step="any" name="Qty3" autocomplete="off" id="Qty3" required><br>
Rate 3:<input type="number" step="any" name="Rate3" autocomplete="off" id="Rate3" class="rate" required><br>
Amount 3:<input readonly type="number" step="any" name="Amt3" autocomplete="off" id="Amt3" required><br><br>

Qty 4:<input type="number" step="any" name="Qty4" autocomplete="off" id="Qty4" required><br>
Rate 4:<input type="number" step="any" name="Rate4" autocomplete="off" id="Rate4"  required><br>
Amount 4:<input readonly type="number" step="any" name="Amt4" autocomplete="off" id="Amt4" required><br><br>

Total Invoice Value:<input readonly type="number" step="any" name="TotalInvoiceValue" id="TotalInvoiceValue" pattern=".{1,}" autocomplete="off" required><br>

</form>

<script>
    $('#Rate1').keyup(function(){
        var Qty1;
        var Rate1;
        textone = parseFloat($('#Qty1').val());
        texttwo = parseFloat($('#Rate1').val());
        var result = textone * texttwo;
        $('#Amt1').val(result.toFixed(2));


    });

    $('#Rate2').keyup(function(){
        var Qty2;
        var Rate2;
        textone = parseFloat($('#Qty2').val());
        texttwo = parseFloat($('#Rate2').val());
        var result = textone * texttwo;
        $('#Amt2').val(result.toFixed(2));


    });
    $('#Rate3').keyup(function(){
        var Qty3;
        var Rate3;
        textone = parseFloat($('#Qty3').val());
        texttwo = parseFloat($('#Rate3').val());
        var result = textone * texttwo;
        $('#Amt3').val(result.toFixed(2));


    });
        $('#Rate4').keyup(function(){
        var Qty4;
        var Rate4;
        textone = parseFloat($('#Qty4').val());
        texttwo = parseFloat($('#Rate4').val());
        var result = textone * texttwo;
        $('#Amt4').val(result.toFixed(2));


    });

    $('#Rate4').keyup(function(){
        var Amt1;
        var Amt2;
        var Amt3;
        var Amt4;
        textone = parseFloat($('#Amt1').val());
        texttwo = parseFloat($('#Amt2').val());
        textthree = parseFloat($('#Amt3').val());
        textfour = parseFloat($('#Amt4').val());
        var result = textone + texttwo + textthree + textfour;
        $('#TotalInvoiceValue').val(result.toFixed(2));


    });
</script>
```

I tried to get the javascript to start taking totals from rate 1 itself by adding multiple element name in the #TotalInvoiceValue function like this:

```
$('#Rate1, #Rate2, #Rate3, #Rate4').keyup(function(){
    var Amt1;
    var Amt2;
    var Amt3;
    var Amt4;
    textone = parseFloat($('#Amt1').val());
    texttwo = parseFloat($('#Amt2').val());
    textthree = parseFloat($('#Amt3').val());
    textfour = parseFloat($('#Amt4').val());
    var result = textone + texttwo + textthree + textfour;
    $('#TotalInvoiceValue').val(result.toFixed(2));


});
```

But it still doesn't work.

I also tried assiging same class to all the Rate inputs like this:

html

```
<input id="Rate1" class="rate" type="text">
<input id="Rate2" class="rate" type="text">
<input id="Rate3" class="rate" type="text">
<input id="Rate4" class="rate" type="text">
```

javascript

```
$('.rate').on('keyup', function() {
  let result = 0;
  $('.rate').each(function() { result += parseFloat(this.value); });
  $('#TotalInvoiceValue').val(result.toFixed(2));
})
```

And even this is not working for me. Please help.

Comment: Am I understanding you correctly? You are asking how to do an if statement.... `If(val1 > 0 && val2 > 0 && val3 > 0 && val4 > 0) { $('#TotalInvoiceValue').val((val1+val2+val3+val4).toFixed(2));}`

Comment: Yes something like this. I thought of If statements as well, but I wanted to see if it can be done without it or not.

Comment: You will need an  if statement, but you can do it more programatically... I'll post an answer..

Comment: The last version you show looks good, but you want to make sure that the parseFloat is a number. You can use isNan(value), or something like a = a || 0

Comment: @CodyCoderson If you establish an initial value on each input/output involved (ex. `value='0'`) then NaN never happens. See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

In the Demo the following was used:

- [**HTMLFormControlsCollection API**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormControlsCollection)
- **[`<input type="number">`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/number)**
- **[`<output></output>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/output)**
- **[`oninput` On-event Property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/input)**
- [**Event Delegation**](https://www.kirupa.com/html5/handling_events_for_many_elements.htm)

**Note:** This is pure JavaScript.

If each input and output element has an initial value:

```
<input id="N0" type="number" value="0">

...

<input id="N*" type="number" value="0">

<output id="T0">0</output>
```

Then expressions like this will always be displayed as a number which is important if your event handler listens on an event that has an immediate reaction (ex. `input`, `keypress`, etc):

```
 T0.value = N0.valueAsNumber + N1.valueAsNumber + ...N(N).valueAsNumber
```

Even though the only input the user uses was `N0` at the time, `N1` thu `N(N)` is still included in expression because they started off with `value="0"`.

---

### Demo

---

```js
var sum = document.forms.sum;

var f = sum.elements;
var n0 = f.N0;
var n1 = f.N1;
var n2 = f.N2;
var n3 = f.N3;
var t0 = f.T0;

sum.oninput = add;

function add(e) {
  if (e.target.className === "N") {
    t0.value = n0.valueAsNumber + n1.valueAsNumber + n2.valueAsNumber + n3.valueAsNumber;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
  return false;
}
```

```css
input {
  font: inherit;
  display: block;
  width: 6ch
}
```

```html
<form id='sum'>

  <input id='N0' type='number' class='N' value='0'>
  <input id='N1' type='number' class='N' value='0'>
  <input id='N2' type='number' class='N' value='0'>
  <input id='N3' type='number' class='N' value='0'>

  <output id='T0'>0</output>

</form>
```

Comment: Try running this code - you get some funky results in the output

Comment: OOPs, thanks for catching that, I've updated now it is functional.

Answer (score 0):

**JSFiddle Example**

https://jsfiddle.net/o2gxgz9r/47359/

**HTML**

```
<div>
    Value 1: <input class="val" id="val1">
    <br/>
    Value 2: <input class="val" id="val2">
    <br/>
    Value 3: <input class="val" id="val3">
    <br/>
    Value 4: <input class="val" id="val4">
    <br/>
    Result: <input class="result">
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var handleChange = function() {
    var result = 0;
    var setResult = true;

    $(".val").each(function(){
        if($(this).val() > 0) {      
        result += parseInt($(this).val());
      } else {
        setResult = false;
      }
    })
    $(".result").val(setResult ? result : '');
  };


  $(".val").change(handleChange);
});
```

Comment: If I put a value in Value 1, I want that value to start reflecting on the Result field immediately in real time. Not after the Value 4 input.

Comment: then remove the setResult flag

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all of your answers. Using your suggestions, this is how my problem got fixed:

HTML:

```
<form name="register" id="myForm" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="register" method="POST">

Qty :<input type="number" step="any" name="Qty1" autocomplete="off" id="Qty1" required><br>
Rate:<input type="number" step="any" name="Rate1" autocomplete="off" id="Rate1" class="rate" required><br>
Amount :<input readonly type="number" step="any" name="Amt1" autocomplete="off" id="Amt1" class="amt" required><br><br>

Qty :<input type="number" step="any" name="Qty2" autocomplete="off" id="Qty2" required><br>
Rate:<input type="number" step="any" name="Rate2" autocomplete="off" id="Rate2" class="rate" required><br>
Amount :<input readonly type="number" step="any" name="Amt2" autocomplete="off" id="Amt2" class="amt" required><br><br>

Qty :<input type="number" step="any" name="Qty3" autocomplete="off" id="Qty3" required><br>
Rate:<input type="number" step="any" name="Rate3" autocomplete="off" id="Rate3" class="rate" required><br>
Amount :<input readonly type="number" step="any" name="Amt3" autocomplete="off" id="Amt3" class="amt" required><br><br>

Qty :<input type="number" step="any" name="Qty4" autocomplete="off" id="Qty4" required><br>
Rate:<input type="number" step="any" name="Rate4" autocomplete="off" id="Rate4" class="rate" required><br>
Amount :<input readonly type="number" step="any" name="Amt4" autocomplete="off" id="Amt4" class="amt" required><br><br>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
    $('#Rate1').keyup(function(){
        var Qty1;
        var Rate1;
        textone = parseFloat($('#Qty1').val());
        texttwo = parseFloat($('#Rate1').val());
        var result = textone * texttwo;
        $('#Amt1').val(result.toFixed(2));


    });

    $('#Rate2').keyup(function(){
        var Qty2;
        var Rate2;
        textone = parseFloat($('#Qty2').val());
        texttwo = parseFloat($('#Rate2').val());
        var result = textone * texttwo;
        $('#Amt2').val(result.toFixed(2));


    });
    $('#Rate3').keyup(function(){
        var Qty3;
        var Rate3;
        textone = parseFloat($('#Qty3').val());
        texttwo = parseFloat($('#Rate3').val());
        var result = textone * texttwo;
        $('#Amt3').val(result.toFixed(2));


    });
        $('#Rate4').keyup(function(){
        var Qty4;
        var Rate4;
        textone = parseFloat($('#Qty4').val());
        texttwo = parseFloat($('#Rate4').val());
        var result = textone * texttwo;
        $('#Amt4').val(result.toFixed(2));


    });

$('.rate').on('keyup', function() {
    var result = 0;
    var setResult = true;
  $('.amt').each(function() {
if($(this).val() > 0) { 
result += parseFloat(this.value);
}
});
  $('#TotalInvoiceValue').val(result.toFixed(2));
});
```